# What is the best way to initialize a class model fields based on primary field/key/mappings?

Tags: java

If I have a class Model which represent the actual price and discounted price of an item.

```
public class Item {
 private String name;
 private double actualPrice;
 private double discountPrice;
}
```

I will get an input with the Item Object which have only "name" field initialized. I need to initialize the other fields with actualPrice and discountPrice based on enums or constants or etc.. (not with HahsMaps). How can I do that efficiently ?

Comment: You'll need to give more detail of exactly what you want to do, and show the sources of the prices.

Comment: Use Builder pattern for this case

Comment: I would like to know what can be used as sources for the prices